# What are the minimum capabilities to update cgroup inside a container?

Tags: docker, cgroups

I'd like to update cgroup inside a container. E.g. create a sub-cgroup inside current container's cgroup.
I found cgroups are mounted as 'ro' unless I create the container with --privileged. I know using privileged mode is not recommended but I don't find a way to achieve it without privileged mode.
What are the minimum capabilities or SecrityContext to make cgroups mount with read-write?